# Chrome Extension Background Page and Content Script Synchronization

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Suppose I have the following code in my background page of a Chrome extension.

```
var opts;
chrome.storage.local.get(options, function(result) {
    opts = result[options];
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, response) {
    if (request.message === 'getOpts')
        response(opts);
});
```

In my content script, I access `opts` with message passing.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'message': 'getOpts'}, function(response) {
    console.log(opts);
});
```

Is there any guarantee that opts will be defined prior to a content script running? For example, when starting up the browser, the background page will run, and presumably the callback to `chrome.storage.local.get` will be added to the background page's message queue. Will Chrome finish processing that queue before injecting content scripts?

I could call chrome.storage.local.get from the content script, but my question is more generic, as I have additional async processing in my background page. At the moment, my content script checks with the background page to make sure everything is ready (using an interval to keep checking), but I am not sure whether such checks are necessary.

Comment: Show us your message passing then. Hard to answer otherwise.

Comment: Hi Xan, I added code showing the message passing.

Comment: It seems like there would be no guarantee. Even if Chrome processes all messages on the background script's queue before loading content scripts, it seems possible that by the time the background script is done running, the callback to chrome.storage.local.get may not be on the queue yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not rely on your variable being defined even if it is in your tests. In general, due to normal timing, your var should be set by the time it receives the message, but to be sure you should check so in your background onMessage. I've dealt with this by remembering in a global whether I've already initialized the extension and do so if needed from onMessage. The answer by xan shows how to use "return true" in that case to process the message once your async init finishes.

See an example of this on [my chrome extension](https://github.com/zmandel/Plus-for-Trello/blob/master/source/background.js#L731) (search for `bCalled`)

There you can see I have a sendResponse method that takes care of detecting if the callback was already called and if not, return true (assumes an async operation is in progress and will call the callback later)

You can also experiment and test this by faking a delay in the background code that loads that var.

Comment: Hi Zig, thanks for the reply. I already have code in place that checks whether everything is ready, and proceeds accordingly. I was curious if such code was necessary, and I am interpreting your post as suggesting the checks are necessary.

Comment: It may or may not be necessary today, but its best to add it for the future or unforseen cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually answer asynchronously to a message.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, response) {
  if (request.message === 'getOpts') {
    chrome.storage.local.get('options', function(result) {
      response(result[options]);
    });
    return true; // Indicate that response() will be called asynchronously
  }
});
```

In case of `chrome.storage` this is, indeed, stupid as the API was specifically designed to addess the roundabout nature of using `localStorage` + Messaging in content scripts; you can query from content scripts directly.

But in general case of async processing, you can postpone answering to the message. You just need to return a true value from the listener to indicate that you're not done yet.

Comment: Hi Xan, thanks for the reply. I can also call chrome.storage.local.get directly from my content script. However, my question is more generic. I am wondering whether opts will be guaranteed to be defined prior to content scripts being injected.

Comment: Content scripts don't inject on extension load. You have to actually navigate after the extension is loaded to have a content script. So there's a big margin of time normally.

Comment: I was particularly using the browser startup example in my post to account for that issue. (since on browser startup the background page loads, as do content scripts).

Comment: Yeah, I just thought about that case too. I don't know if there are any guarantees regarding that. It's an interesting question how it works on browser startup. I would make that a separate, specific question and it probably needs an answer from someone with experience with Chrome internals, like RobW.

Comment: I mean, I see your point. Is `addListener` even guaranteed to run before a message is sent?

Comment: I once did some tests that logged times in the console from background pages and content scripts. From what I recall, content scripts were injected *after* the background page finished loading, so the addListener call would have run in your example. I think the scenario becomes less clear in the type of example I gave, where a callback in the background page has to run (I suppose there is no guarantee for such cases, so I'll keep my code that checks that everything is ready).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75317/discussion-between-xan-and-daniel-s).